# siunitx: Preventing decimal point alignment and adding spaces around tabular columns using table-space-text-pre/post

Tags: tabularx, siunitx

In the following, is it possible to make `table-space-text-pre = \hspace{2ex}` and `table-space-text-post = \hspace{2ex}` add extra space around their respective columns while preventing decimal point alignment by using `table-parse-only`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{
            >{\RaggedLeft}X
            S[table-format = 4.3,
            table-parse-only,
            table-number-alignment = right,
            round-mode = off,
            tight-spacing = true,
            table-space-text-pre = \hspace{2ex},
            table-space-text-post = \hspace{2ex},
            ]
            s[table-unit-alignment = left,
            table-space-text-pre = \hspace{2ex},
            ]
        }
    another text & 1400  & \kilo\gram \\
    another text & 0.015 & \m \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would just cheat and add two extra columns and let them be spacers

Comment: Should the numbers in the second column be centered, left-aligned, or right-aligned?

Comment: @Mico right-aligned

Comment: @daleif This workaround is working, but it will need to add a lot of column separators in the table, which is not handy.

Comment: Just use `X@{\hspace{2ex}}S[...]@{\hspace{2ex}s[...]}` in the table preamble.

Comment: @HenriMenke It will break the row color as shown [here](https://i.ibb.co/x2D1STx/image.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily solved by using only `>{\hspace{2ex}}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{
            >{\RaggedLeft}X
            >{\hspace{1ex}}S[
            table-format = 4.3,
            table-parse-only,
            table-number-alignment = right,
            round-mode = off,
            tight-spacing = true,
            ]<{\hspace{2ex}}
            s[
            table-unit-alignment = left,
            ]
        }
        another text & 1400  & \kilo\gram \\
        another text & 0.015 & \m \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Until now I didn't noticed your answer, (which you accepted!) . Now I wonder, in what it is different from mine?

Comment: @Zarko Your comment made me realize I didn't have to write and accept my answer since the solution is already in yours :/

Answer (score 2):

I must confess that I don't understand your problem well. First you set `\tabcolsep` to zero, but then you require spaces between columns ...
Anyway, I guessing, that you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{>{\RaggedLeft}X 
                                    >{\hskip 1em}r<{\,}
                                    s}
    another text & 1400  & \kilo\gram \\
    another text & 0.015 & \m \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

which generates the following table:

[image]

Of course, this require that you define space around column manually. If you have a number of similar cases, than the defining new colummn  type can be handy. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\hskip 1em}r<{\,}} % <---
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{>{\RaggedLeft}X
                                    R % <---
                                    s}
    another text & 1400  & \kilo\gram \\
    another text & 0.015 & \m \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I still need to use S columns to be able use the other features of siunitx such as scientific notation. Also, setting the round-mode to off is temporary in this example, and I might turn it on later.

Comment: @Diaa, As you present the question and try to clarify in comments, in this particular case you not need `S` column in the second column.  BTW, you was not satisfied with egreg answer which use `S` column, so he deleted it) Sorry, your question is not clear.