# tabular: Overfull \hbox (too wide) detected at line

Tags: tables, warnings

Why do I have this message

> Overfull \hbox (8.62pt too wide) detected at line 26

for the following?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,ragged2e,booktabs,lipsum}
\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\hspace{-0.5ex}}\cdot{\hspace{-0.5ex}}},
    sticky-per,
    per-mode = symbol,
    bracket-unit-denominator,
    forbid-literal-units,
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\radpers}{\radian\s\tothe{-1}}
\begin{document}
    \tabcolsep0pt
    \begin{tabular}{
            >{\RaggedRight}m{0.4\linewidth}
            >{\RaggedRight}m{0.1\linewidth}
            S[
            table-number-alignment=right,
            ]<{\hspace{2ex}}
            s[
            inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\hspace{-0.5ex}}\cdot{\hspace{-0.5ex}}},
            table-unit-alignment = left,
            ]
        }
        \toprule
        text & text & 5 & \N\m\per\radpers\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: You may to replace `inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\hspace{-0.5ex}}\cdot{\hspace{-0.5ex}}}` with `inter-unit-product = {{\cdot}}`.

Comment: @Zarko it won't work with table-parse-only as I asked before here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566277/2288

Comment: oh, now I see that this was my suggestion to you in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559134/siunitx-preventing-decimal-point-alignment-and-adding-spaces-around-tabular-col/559174#559174 :-)